# Regroup results in a row

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I think it is a very simple question, but yet I didn't find anything helpful.

I make 3 selections that looks like this:

```
SELECT count(*) as nbTable1
FROM table1, joinTable
WHERE table1.A = joinTable.A;

SELECT count(*) as nbTable2
FROM table2, joinTable
WHERE table1.A = joinTable.A;

SELECT count(*) as nbTable3
FROM table3, joinTable
WHERE table1.A = joinTable.A;
```

I would like to group the results in one row:

```
nbTable1 | nbTable2 | nbTable3 |
--------------------------------
      12 |        8 |       15 |
```

---

I tried to `UNION` the results, but I get

```
nbTable1 |
----------
      12 |
       8 |
      15 |
```

---

I can't make it in a single `select` because of the `joinTable` I use in each request... May you help me? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
      (SELECT count(*)
         FROM table1, joinTable
        WHERE table1.A = joinTable.A) nbTable1,
      (SELECT count(*)
         FROM table2, joinTable
        WHERE table2.A = joinTable.A) nbTable2,
      (SELECT count(*)
         FROM table3, joinTable
        WHERE table3.A = joinTable.A) nbTable3
 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I removed `as nbTable1` after count(*), because it does not bring anything :)